# Excel shortcut for last cell position

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut to get the last position of a cell in Excel. I found the following:

> `fn5` -> `Alt + s` -> `s` -> `Enter`

Is there any other way to get it?

Comment: Last position with regard to _what_?  The row, the column, something else?

Comment: if you are considering as column than CTRL + DOWN KEY

Comment: On a mac, for a column it is CMND + DOWN key...

Comment: For bottom right-hand corner of used range, Ctrl-End

Comment: Also see this for resetting a used range https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107047/force-refresh-of-last-cell-of-the-worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + G then enter takes you back to last active cell. Demonstration in this video along with another cool shortcut: Ctrl + [

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7F4yPSSUBeo