Faster way to load an XLSX file with multiple sheets into R
I am looking for a faster way to read 12-sheet XLSX files into R. I am processing data from an instrument that can can analyze up to 12 samples at once, and each sample gets its own sheet in the spreadsheet, so the XLSX file can contain up to 12 sheets. Each sheet contains 29 rows and 202 columns.
The computer used for processing the data is a Windows 11 box with 12 cores and 16 GB RAM running R 4.4.1. I'm reading the file from an SSD.
I've tried the following methods (in triplicate to get confidence intervals), but average times have not been faster than 47.0 seconds. In fact, everything I've tried except using future_map() with 2 cores has been about the same speed. The table and plot show the times for each method, and the code is at the bottom.
Any suggestions on speeding things up?



Method
Mean Time (s)
95% Confidence Interval (s)




for() read_excel() preallocate
49.9
8.59


future_map() read_excel() 2 cores
81.4
21.8


future_map() read_excel() 4 cores
47.0
5.49


future_map() read_excel() 8 cores
54.6
10.0


future_map() read_excel() 12 cores
54.8
9.97


lapply() read_excel() preallocate
54.1
7.61


read_excel()
53.6
14.3


read_excel() preallocate
49.4
7.79


read_xlsx()
56.7
9.34


read_xlsx() preallocate
52.8
14.4




The code:
library(readxl) # for read_excel() and read_xlsx()
library(dplyr) # for %>%
library(purrr) # for map
library(furrr) # for future_map

# foo.xlsx contains 12 sheets, and each sheet has 29 rows and 202 columns of data
  my_filename <- "foo.xlsx"
  my_sheets <- excel_sheets(filename)

# for() and read_excel() with preallocation
  my_data <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(my_sheets))
  for(i in 1:length(my_sheets)){
    my_data[[i]] <- read_excel(path = my_filename, sheet=my_sheets[i],
                            col_names = FALSE)
  }

# lapply() and read_excel() with preallocation
  my_data <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(my_sheets))
  my_data <- lapply(my_sheets, FUN = read_excel, path = my_filename)

# map() with read_excel() and read_xlsx(), with and without preallocation
  # my_data <- vector(mode = "list", length = 12) #uncomment for preallocation
  my_data <- 
    filename %>% 
    excel_sheets() %>% 
    set_names() %>% 
    map(read_excel, path = my_filename, col_names = FALSE)
    # map(read_xlsx, path = my_filename, col_names = FALSE) # alternative 

# future_map with read_excel()
  plan(multisession, workers = 2) #also 4, 8, and 12
  my_data <- 
    filename %>% 
    excel_sheets() %>% 
    set_names() %>% 
    future_map(read_excel, path = my_filename, col_names = FALSE)

Edited to add how the data in the sheets are formatted:
Sample Name

Heading 1
x1 [data listed horizontally]
y1 [data listed horizontally]

Heading 2
x2 [data listed horizontally]
y2 [data listed horizontally]

Heading 3
x3 [data listed horizontally]
y3 [data listed horizontally]

Heading 4
x4 [data listed horizontally]
y4 [data listed horizontally]

Heading 5
x5 [data listed horizontally]
y5 [data listed horizontally]

Heading 6
x6 [data listed horizontally]
y6 [data listed horizontally]

Heading 7
x7 [data listed horizontally]
y7 [data listed horizontally]


I'm surprised it's taking so long. Just to test, I created an Excel file with 12 sheets, each with 202 columns and 29 rows of data. It took less than 2 seconds (on an eight-year-old windows computer) to read in all the data using map to iterate over all the sheets. Is it possible there's something unusual or unexpected about the formatting of these sheets that could be slowing things down?

One possibility that occurs to me is that maybe the sheets' last cells are not GT29 but rather something much larger. This could happen inadvertently, if, for instance, the sheet used have data beyond that range, or there is formatting beyond that range. If that were the case, your functions might be checking millions of cells instead of around 6,000. That could potentially be addressed at the sheet (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107047/force-refresh-of-last-cell-of-the-worksheet), or by specifying the read function only look to the expected range.

@eipi10 That's a good question. The data in the sheets aren't very tidy with a lot of empty spaces, and I'm having to clean them up after loading everything.

Taking up the hint from @JonSpring, you could specify the cell range you want to read, i.e. the 202 columns and 29 rows. Personally I‘m using the openxlsx package to read in Excel files. From my experience this package gives the most flexibility.

@JonSpring I tried using map(read_excel, path = filename, col_names = FALSE, range = "A1:GT29") and still got a read time of 54.4 +/- 12.3 s.

I also tried specifying that the first column should be formatted as text and all the other columns as numeric: map(read_excel, path = filename, col_names = FALSE, range = "A1:GT29", col_types=c("text", rep("numeric", 201))). The average read speed was 56.5 +/- 10.4 s.

Would it be possible to share one of those files as an example? Preferably unchanged, coming from that same instrument as-is.

@JonSpring A check of Formulas - Name Manager shows no junk names, and all the sheet names are "Sheet1" through "Sheet12".
